# PHP Apc : how to view cache entries in APC

Tags: php, apache, apc

I have php 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6.

I installed apc by:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

( though i found many other methods later).

I want to see my cache entries and other info. I googled and found finding and placing `apc.php`  file in `/var/www/` will do what I need.

I found no such file through the command

```
$ find -name apc.php | grep apc .
```

what should i do ?

P.S: I'm not an expert and it's my first site.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/165792/where-is-apc-php

Comment: thanks ... it worked ...but why was it not found by that command i used

Answer (score 5):

Simply download one of the archive files that matches your APC version -- http://pecl.php.net/package/APC, browse the archive for the apc.php file and extract it into your docroot and your good to go.

Comment: Also you have to change the password in the apc.php file, then login (top right button) to see the full paths.